# Create a custom string c#

Tags: c#, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a numeric id of integer type. I want to add that integer type value to 00000 and concatenate it with string type variable.Assume my integer variable value is 1. After adding the variable it should look like 00001. And I want to concatenate with a string like "Added" and then convert whole thing to a string variable. like this "Added00001". As another example if my integer value is 111 it should look like "Added00111" at the end. Another example integer variable = 1234. Final string should be "Added01234". How to do it...? An example of how to do it.. or Any tutorial how to do such a thing would be really great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the short form format specifier of the ToString method. In the example below, D5 indicates that the integer 111 should be converted to a string with padded zeros to a length of 5 digits, e.g. 00111.

```
int i = 111;
string s = "Added";
var s = s + i.ToString("D5");

//s = "Added00111"
```

Comment: @chathwind glad to be of help.